# Overriding values in dataframe while joining 2 dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the below example I would like to override the values in Spark Dataframe A with corresponding value in Dataframe B (if it exists). Is there a way to do it using Spark (Scala)?

**Dataframe A**

```
ID Name Age
1  Paul 30
2  Sean 35
3  Rob  25
```

**Dataframe B**

```
ID Name Age
1  Paul 40
```

**Result**

```
ID Name Age
1  Paul 40
2  Sean 35
3  Rob  25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combined use of a `left join` and [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#coalesce) should do the trick, something like:

```scala
dfA
  .join(dfB, "ID", "left")
  .select(
    dfA.col("ID"),
    dfA.col("Name"),
    coalesce(dfB.col("Age"), dfA.col("Age")).as("Age")
  )
```

Explanation: For a specific ID `some_id`, there is 2 cases:

1. if `dfB` does not contain `some_id`: then the left join will produce null for `dfB.col("Age")` and the
   `coalesce` will return the first non-null value from expressions we
   passed to it, i.e. the value of `dfA.col("Age")`
2. if `dfB` contains `some_id` then the value from `dfB.col("Age")` will be used.

Comment: cool. How it is transforms to dfA.id = dfB.id, while you specify only dfB.id in join?

Comment: it's because the signature used is `A.join(B, usingColName, joinType)`, requiring though that both left and right DataFrames have a column named `usingColName`, similarly to the `USING` join syntax in SQL